# Null pointer exception when JOptionPane.showMessageDialog is cancelled

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, joptionpane

Despite efforts reading on how Null Pointer Exceptions are generated, I literally have no clue how this error is generating itself within my code.

I don't think this affects my code directly, as I could just catch the exception, but before I do that, I'd still like to learn more about the error.

Part of my code where the error is generating, I am opening a new Input dialog and waiting for the user's input. If the user cancels the input dialog, it's just meant to close the dialog, in which it does. However, it's giving me an error every time I cancel.

Here's the code:

```
String newInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Your current holdings are: "
        + cable.getHoldings(), "Edit Holdings", JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);

if (newInput.isEmpty())
{
    //Error generated here
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter in a number!");

}

else
{...}
```

The message dialog is only triggered if the user presses the 'OK' button on the input dialog. Otherwise, if a user cancels or exits the input dialog, a null pointer exception error is generated.

Does anyone mind helping me and letting me know why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: post the error log

Comment: http://pastebin.com/v4KFpKj6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From docs](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JOptionPane.java#JOptionPane.showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%29)

> Returns: user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input

so it `retruns` `null` if user cancel the dialog

From `showInputDialog` source code

```
 if (value == UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) {
             return null;
         }
```

Solutions : put a nullity check before doing anything

```
if (newInput==null || newInput.isEmpty())
```

you don't need `newInput.isEmpty()` because it checks the length of a string so even user enters a space length will be 1 or length will be `null` in case of cancelled input so nullity check is only enough for checking some input.

**Improvement** : you can use `regex` to validate your input, is digit or not ,like this

```
if (newInput==null || !newInput.matches("\\d+"))
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter in a number!");

}
```

`\\d+` check the input should contain at-least one or more integer digits.

Comment: Oh wow, that is most interesting. Thank you for your help, I'll be sure to learn from this.

Comment: @juiceb0xk i am glad i could help , use the improvement part , make your logic more robust , happy coding

Answer (score 2):

The issue what I understood is that you are checking the **isEmpty()** method on a null (*newInput*) value which will throw the null pointer exception. You should check this below:

**Instead of this:**

```
if (newInput.isEmpty())
{
    //Error generated here
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter in a number!");
}
```

**Do this :**

```
if (newInput == null)
{
    //Error generated here
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter in a number!");

}
```

This should work fine. Hope this helps...!!!

Comment: it's `newInput == null` not `newInput = null`

Comment: Thank you for your help, it all makes sense now.

Comment: @juiceb0xk: Please accept the answer also if it helps you.